# Measure of an elementary set in terms of cardinality

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

In Terry Tao's textbook on measure theory and integration, he notes that, given an elementary set $A$, the length of $A$, denoted $|A|$, may be written discretely as

$$|A| = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} \#\left(A \cap \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n}\right).$$ Intuitively, this makes sense for intervals of whole numbers... Obviously an interval of length 1 contains 1 integer, etc. But, I don't quite see how to prove this explicitly, or how it works for an interval, say $[e,\pi]$.

How can one go about explicitly proving this discrete notion of length?

Here, $\#$ denotes cardinality. Moreover, $$\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n} : = \{ \frac{a}{n} \, : \,  a \in \mathbb{Z} \}.$$

Comment: What is an elementary set?

Comment: $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n}$ is not the integers. The interval $[0,1)$ contains only one integer, but $n$ many elements of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose that $\#\left(A\cap\frac{\Bbb Z}n\right)=k$, where $(a,b)\subseteq A\subseteq[a,b]$; then

$$\frac{k-1}n\le b-a\le\frac{k+1}n\;.$$

(The extremes are when $A=\left[\frac{m}n,\frac{m+k-1}n\right]$ for some $m\in\Bbb Z$, and when $A=\left(\frac{m}n,\frac{m+k+1}n\right)$ for some $m\in\Bbb Z$.) Equivalently,

$$n(b-a)-1\le\#\left(A\cap\frac{\Bbb Z}n\right)\le n(b-a)+1\;,$$

or

$$b-a-\frac1n\le\frac1n\#\left(A\cap\frac{\Bbb Z}n\right)\le b-a+\frac1n\;.$$

Now just take the limit as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Sorry for my late follow-up, but how did you get $n(b-a)-1\le\#\left(A\cap\frac{\Bbb Z}n\right)\le n(b-a)+1$ immediatelly from $\frac{k-1}n\le b-a\le\frac{k+1}n$? With the same notation, I get $$-1\le n(b-a)-k\le 1,$$ that is $$-1\le n(b-a)-\#\left(A\cap\frac{\Bbb Z}n\right)\le 1\Big/\cdot\frac1n\\\implies \left|\frac1n\#\left(A\cap\frac{\Bbb Z}n\right)-(b-a)\right|\le\frac1n$$ so I get your previous line only after the end.

Comment: @Spring: I did it in my head and figured that it was straightforward enough that I didn’t need to fill in the details: $k-1\le n(b-a)\le k+1$ leads immediately to $k\le n(b-a)+1$ and $k\ge n(b-a)-1$, and I just combined those in a single line, replacing $k$ by $\#\left(A\cap\frac{\Bbb Z}n\right)$.