# Discrete Measure of Interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing

In Terry Tao's Measure Theory, he notes that the length of an interval $|A| = b-a$ may be recovered as

\begin{equation*}|A| = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \# \left(A \cap \frac{\mathbb Z}{N} \right). \qquad (1)\end{equation*}

A year ago today, Brian M. Scott gave a simple proof [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1201854/measure-of-an-elementary-set-in-terms-of-cardinality)

Now this question was asked a year ago, and, since I've not yet entered university, I do like to look at old questions I've asked to see if I can solve them in some way without referring to the intuition of the answer or even looking at the answer.

The following was my attempt this evening, it involved bounding the rhs of the above expression above in an obvious way and below by approximations of compact intervals of the "right" form. All comments appreciated.

Note first that $$\# \left(A \cap \frac{\mathbb Z}{N} \right) \leq (N+1)(b-a).$$

To establish a lower bound, consider the set

$$\Omega := \{\frac{1}{jr}\# \left(B \cap \frac{\mathbb Z}{jr} \right) : B = [\frac{m}{r}-\frac{k_1}{jr}, \frac{m}{r}+\frac{k_2}{jr}] \subset A, \, \text{with} \, \frac{m}{r} \in \frac{\mathbb Z}{r}, j,k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb{N} \}.$$

For sets of the form $B$, notice that $$\frac{1}{pjr} \# \left(B \cap \frac{\mathbb Z}{pjr} \right) = \frac{k_1+k_2}{jr}$$ for all $p \in \mathbb{N}$. By clear montonicity of the RHS of (1), for sets of this form

$$\frac{k_1+k_2}{jr} \leq \lim_{p \to \infty} \frac{1}{pjr} \# \left(A \cap \frac{\mathbb Z}{pjr} \right) \leq  \lim_{p \to \infty} \frac{1}{pjr}(pjr+1)(b-a).$$
I claim in fact $\sup(\Omega) = (b-a)$. Now, clearly $\sup(\Omega) \leq (b-a)$. To see it is the supremum, let $\epsilon >0$ and pick $n$ so that $\frac{2}{n} < \epsilon.$ We wish to show there is $B \subset A$ so that it is of the above form and its discrete cardinality (equivalent to its size) is greater than this value. To do so, let $\alpha$ be the midpoint of $A$. Let $q \in \mathbb Q$ be such that $q-\alpha < \frac{1}{4n}$. Now, $q= \frac{m}{r} \in \frac{\mathbb Z}{r}$. Let $j \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $jr > \frac{4n}{3}$. There exists $k_2$ so that $$ b-\frac{1}{n} < \alpha +\frac{k_2}{jr} < b-\frac{1}{4n}$$ and therefore $$b-\frac{1}{n} < q+\frac{k_2}{jr} < b.$$ Similarly, there is $k_1$ such that $$a < q-\frac{k_1}{jr} < a-\frac{1}{n}.$$

Thus, the interval $B^{*}:= [q-\frac{k_1}{jr}, q-\frac{k_2}{jr}]$ is of the form as $B$, and has value $$\frac{1}{pjr} \# \left(B^{*} \cap \frac{\mathbb Z}{pjr} \right) = \frac{k_1+k_2}{jr} > (b-a)-\epsilon$$ in $\Omega$. Ergo, returning to the original bounds and taking the supremum on the lhs,

$$(b-a) \leq \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \# \left(A \cap \frac{\mathbb Z}{N} \right) \leq \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N}(N+1)(b-a).$$

Since both sides tend to $b-a$, this completes the proof.

Are there issues with this proof? I'm sure there are better ways to express this approximation from the inside by "good" compact intervals (I've sorta cheated by using the idea of inner regularity of the lebesgue measure, but eh). Again, any comments appreciated.

Comment: "By the clear monotonicity of the RHS of (1).".... If A=[1/2, 3/5) the respective values of the RHS of (1) for N=2,3,4 are 1,0,1. Not monotonic.

Comment: @user254665 I meant w.r.t inclusion

Comment: I should have said $A=(2/5,3/5)$. We have $A\cap (Z/2)=A\cap (Z/4)=\{1/2\}$ but$ A\cap (Z/3)=\phi.$

Comment: @user254665 I meant if $B \subseteq A$, $$\frac{1}{N} \# \left(B \cap \frac{\mathbb Z}{N} \right) \leq \frac{1}{N} \# \left(A \cap \frac{\mathbb Z}{N} \right)$$

Comment: ok .That makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to get a good lower bound for the RHS of (1): Let $[x]$ denote the largest integer not exceeding $x$.

For $n\in N$ we have $a n<[a n+1]$ and $[b n-1]< b n.$ So  when $j\in Z$, we have $$[a n+1]\leq j\leq [b n-1]\implies a n<j<b n\implies  a<j/n<b.$$ Therefore, with $N=n$, the RHS of (1) is at least  $$f(n)=n^{-1}\cdot\max (0, [b n-1]-[a n+1]+1).$$ We have $[b n-1]> b n-2$ and $[a n+1]\leq a n+1$, so $$[b n-1]-[a n+1]+1>(b n-2)-(a n+1)+1=(b-a)n-2.$$ So for $n\geq 2/(b-a)$ we have $$f(n)/n>[(b-a)n-2]/n=(b-a)-2/n.$$

Comment: comments on what I've provided?

Comment: I will examine it tomorrow. This minute I'm getting sleepy. Don't want to risk saying something dumb.

Comment: no worries, thank you

Comment: bounty expires soon...