# Discrete Size of Sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $A \subset B \subset \mathbb{R}$, with $A$, $B$ intervals, how do I show  that

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \, \frac{1}{n} \#(A \cap \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n}) \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \,\frac{1}{n} \#(B \cap \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n})?$$

here $\#$ denotes cardinality, and $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n} : = \{\frac{z}{n} : z \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

In particular, the proof I've given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720432/discrete-measure-of-interval) seems to require this fact, but I just wanted to confirm it's true. Namely, I want to verify this without using the fact that both of these limits actually exist, because that would make the proof I've given useless. I only need this weaker fact.

Intuitively it seems rather easy since these are intervals. Here's a sketch of what I mean:

let $\{a_n\}$ be a subsequence of the values $\#(A \cap \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n})$ converging to the limsup and $\{b_n\}$ the liminf of the expression with $B$. Then, for each $n$ that gives $a_n$, we can take a much larger $N$ for $b_N$. If $N$ is taken large enough (say, so that $\frac{1}{N}$ is smaller than the leftover space in $A \setminus \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n}$, and smaller than the space between $A$ and $B$), then $a_n \leq b_N$. Since we can always find an element of the latter subsequence bigger than the former, we have the inequality.

Does this sketch work?

**I've added an answer below, please comment on it if you have a chance**

Comment: From the other question, it looks like there is a $1/n$ missing from each limit, ie $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac1n\#(A\cap\frac{\mathbb Z}n)$.

Comment: @stewbasic yes indeed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I believe to be an answer:

Let $n, a_n$ be as in the question. Let $\#(A \cap \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n}) = k+1$, which means there are $k$ intervals of length $\frac{1}{n}$. Now let $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2$ be the left and right gaps between $A$ and $B$, i.e., if $A := [a,b]$ and $B = [c,d]$ (or any type of interval), $\epsilon_1 = c-a$, $\epsilon_2 = b-d$.

Let $\frac{1}{N} < \frac{1}{k}\min\{\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\}$, or smaller than the non-zero $\epsilon$ times $\frac{1}{k}$. Then let $b_N$ be an element of the liminf sequence. We see first that there are $k *\operatorname{floor}(\frac{N}{n})$ intervals of length $\frac{1}{N}$ in $A$. By choice of $N$, we have the following inequalities:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
a_n = \frac{k+1}{n} = \frac{(k+1)\frac{N}{n}}{N}  &<& \frac{(k+1)*\operatorname{floor}(\frac{N}{n}) + k+1}{n}   \\
&<& \frac{1}{N}\#(B \cap \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{N}) \\
&=& b_N
\end{eqnarray*}$$

where the second inequality comes from the choice of $N$, since we may fit enough intervals into the gap between $A$ and $B$ to get at least $k+1$ more endpoints.

Thus, the limit of $a_n$ which is the limsup is less than the limit of $b_n$, the lim inf.